# VNC session turns undead over the weekend

Tags: vnc

During the week I have a single VNC session I'm working with throughout the week. However, whenever I come back from the weekend or some vacation, I can no longer connect to that session, getting a "cannot connect to host: Connection refused (10061)".

When I ssh to the server and use `vncserver -list`, I **do** see my session there, and it looks very much alive; and I can open additional sessions and connect to them. If I try to `vncserver -kill` the original session, though, I get a

```
Xvnc process ID $ID already killed
```

message.

What's going on here, and I can I keep my session alive over time?

Server is running Redhat 6.